# Unexpected behaviour of Prolog code

Tags: prolog

I want to ask about this code , why List L2 keep it's values when functions start to return it's value from Recursion , it's like 'Holding' it self , i think that list L2 must return to it's original value !!

```
my_reverse(L1,L2) :- my_rev(L1,L2,[]).

my_rev([],L2,L2) :- !.
my_rev([X|Xs],L2,Acc) :- my_rev(Xs,L2,[X|Acc]).
```

Comment: It performs as expected. `L2` in your `my_rev/3` predicate isn't instantiated until the base case. After instantiation, it isn't touched until recursion completes.

Comment: @mbratch i think the following question is a stuped question , but is it should be to go back to it's original situation "uninitialized "

Comment: No it wouldn't revert back. That would only happen on backtracking. The code isn't backtracking, but returning from recursions and instantiating `L2` along the way until your query to `my_reverse/2` is fulfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L2 doesn't keep its value. The program is supposed to be called as follows:

```
?- my_reverse([1,2,3,4], Z).
Z = [4, 3, 2, 1].
```

L2 is unified with Z in this example. It is kept unassigned until the first rule of the my_rev predicated is matched. Then the accumulator is unified with L2: in the last step the contents of the accumulator is "assigned to" L2.

Comment: okay , you explantion get my problem to being solve , however whar about --> my_rev([],L2,L2) :- !. <-- what it does do ?

Comment: @Hassan  `my_rev([], L2, L2) :- !.` attempts to unify the 2nd and 3rd parameters of `my_rev/3` and, if it succeeds, will cut any backtracking (Prolog won't seek any additional solutions).

Comment: @mbratch , okay, Thank you for your helps today , however , The '!' sign tell Prolog to stop and return results , right ?

Comment: @Hassan, a result can be obtained whether there's a cut or no cut. The cut prevents prolog from backtracking once the cut has been reached. You can see some other simple example here: http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse44. Cuts are to be used sparingly and very purposefully. If used carelessly, they can prevent desired backtracking to provide solutions that may be wanted.